# Is there a better R way to expand a dataframe by a function on rows?

Tags: r, group

## Question:

Below works, but is there a better "R way" of achieving similar result? I am essentially trying to create / distribute groups into individual line items according to a user defined function (currently just using a loop).

## Example:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "C"), 
              volume = c(200L, 45L, 104L)
              )
print(df1)
#>   group volume
#> 1     A    200
#> 2     B     45
#> 3     C    104
```

I want the `volume` to be broken across multiple rows according to group so that the final result is a dataframe where the new volume (`vol2` in the below) would add up to original volume above.  In this example, I'm applying integer math with a divisor of 52, so my final result should be:

```r
print(df3)
#>    group vol2
#> 1      A   52
#> 2      A   52
#> 3      A   52
#> 4      A   44
#> 21     B   45
#> 31     C   52
#> 32     C   52
```

### This works

The code below **DOES** get me to the desired result shown above:

```r
div <- 52L
df1$intgr <- df1$volume %/% div
df1$remainder <- df1$volume %% div

print(df1)
#>   group volume intgr remainder
#> 1     A    200     3        44
#> 2     B     45     0        45
#> 3     C    104     2         0

df2 <- data.frame()

for (r in 1:nrow(df1)){
  if(df1[r,"intgr"] > 0){
    for (k in 1:as.integer(df1[r,"intgr"])){
      df1[r,"vol2"] <- div
      df2 <- rbind(df2, df1[r,])
    }
  }
  if(df1[r,"remainder"]>0){
    df1[r, "vol2"] <- as.integer(df1[r, "remainder"])
    df2 <- rbind(df2, df1[r,])
  }
}

print(df2)
#>    group volume intgr remainder vol2
#> 1      A    200     3        44   52
#> 2      A    200     3        44   52
#> 3      A    200     3        44   52
#> 4      A    200     3        44   44
#> 21     B     45     0        45   45
#> 31     C    104     2         0   52
#> 32     C    104     2         0   52

df3 <- subset(df2, select = c("group", "vol2"))

print(df3)
#>    group vol2
#> 1      A   52
#> 2      A   52
#> 3      A   52
#> 4      A   44
#> 21     B   45
#> 31     C   52
#> 32     C   52
```

Being still relatively new to R, I'm just curious if someone knows a better way / function / method that gets to the same place.  Seems like there might be. I could potentially have a more complex way of breaking up the rows and I was thinking maybe there's a method that applies a UDF to the dataframe to do something like this.  I was searching for "expand group/groups" but was finding mostly "expand.grid" which isn't what I'm doing here.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Why does the 4th row of `vol2` column show 44, not 52 as its first three rows?

Comment: @AbdurRohman - `200 %% 52` is `44` - it's the remainder after breaking out the `200` into rows of `52` each.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick function to help split each number by the modulus,

```r
fun <- function(num, mod) c(rep(mod, floor(num / mod)), (num-1) %% mod + 1)
fun(200, 52)
# [1] 52 52 52 44
fun(45, 52)
# [1] 45
fun(104, 52)
# [1] 52 52
```

And we can apply this a number of ways:

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(vol2 = fun(volume, 52), .groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#   group  vol2
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 A        52
# 2 A        52
# 3 A        52
# 4 A        44
# 5 B        45
# 6 C        52
# 7 C        52
```

## base R

```r
do.call(rbind, by(df1, seq(nrow(df1)),
                  FUN = function(z) data.frame(group = z$group, vol2 = fun(z$volume, 52))))
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df1[, .(vol2 = fun(volume, 52)), by = group]
```

Comment: Really nice and simple.

Comment: Thanks @stefan ... though I think the base R code shows why we need something like dplyr's and data.table's code to easily calculate by-group

Comment: Mind==>BLOWN!  You are using `group_by()/summarize()` to **EXPAND** a dataframe?  I had no idea it would do that, as I have only experienced `summarize` for collapsing a dataframe.  Still wrapping my head around that.  Appreciate the multiple solutions, and I'm reading up on data.table as I'm unfamiliar.  I love the function, but question: Beyond personal preference, is there a reason you used `ceiling(num / mod)-1` instead of slightly shorter (and more obvious to me) `floor(num / mod)`?  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No reason for ceiling over floor, there were some quick iterations on possible solutions, and when I tried that it worked and I didn't look back to reduce it to `floor`.

Comment: TBH, I don't recall exactly when `summarize` started allowing more than 1 row per group; if you look at the newest blog post about the [`dplyr-1.1.0` impending release](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/dplyr-1-1-0-is-coming-soon/), you'll see reference to `reframe` as a way to visualize `summarize` but allowing it to return more than just 1 row. Perhaps they've been silently testing the premise, I don't know. But it's been working for me, at least with 1.0.8, not sure about earlier.

Comment: I like `data.table`, and for some projects and some people, I strongly recommend it. There is a learning curve, but when you get past the hump of that curve, it starts paying in some nice dividends, mostly when your data gets to be a bit big. Having said that ... the way `dplyr` can operate lazily on some things like SQL databases and arrow/parquet dataset connections is very powerful. They can do similar (lazy) things using `dtplyr` (with which I have no experience).

Comment: Yes, I did.  USNA '97 grad.  Seven years active as a sub nuke (USS ASHEVILLE 758) and got out in 2004.  Good people, good friends.  I expect `flying > submerging` -- except when surface OOD in the morning off Pearl Harbor ;-).  Carry on, sir!

Comment: Not sure about `>`, I lean more heavily towards `!=`. Though ... subs don't get much of a ground-rush from speeding, not visually at least.

Comment: Reading that [dplyr-1.1.0 impending release](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/dplyr-1-1-0-is-coming-soon/) a bit more carefully, it looks like the `group_by()/summarize()` solution will **NOT** work once that release occurs, but that `reframe()` function is specifically being created to do that.  I am not going to install the test version to check it now, but once that comes out, I think that your answer may benefit from an update.

Answer (score 3):

A `tidyverse` approach using `purrr::pmap` and `tidyr::unnest_longer` may look like so:

```r
library(dplyr, w = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

div <- 52

df1 |> 
  mutate(intgr = volume %/% div, remainder = volume %% div, intgr1 = +(remainder > 0)) |> 
  mutate(vol2 = purrr::pmap(list(intgr, intgr1, remainder), ~ c(rep(div, ..1), rep(..3, ..2)))) |> 
  tidyr::unnest_longer(vol2) |> 
  select(-intgr1)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 5
#>   group volume intgr remainder  vol2
#>   <chr>  <int> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A        200     3        44    52
#> 2 A        200     3        44    52
#> 3 A        200     3        44    52
#> 4 A        200     3        44    44
#> 5 B         45     0        45    45
#> 6 C        104     2         0    52
#> 7 C        104     2         0    52
```

Comment: This is a great answer, too.  I was thinking something along the lines of `pivot_longer` was what I would want, but couldn't see a way to use it, and the `unnest_longer()` was unknown to me until now (I have so much to learn!).  Your use of `+(remainder > 0)` is a short cut instead of `as.integer()` to coerce the logical?  Why does that work?  It's shorter, but I haven't seen that before.  Thank you very much for this answer!

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table` and `rep`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)[, .(vol2 = c(rep(52, volume%/%52), (volume%%52)[sign(volume%%52)])), group]
#>    group vol2
#> 1:     A   52
#> 2:     A   52
#> 3:     A   52
#> 4:     A   44
#> 5:     B   45
#> 6:     C   52
#> 7:     C   52
```

Or

```
setDT(df1)[, .(vol2 = c(rep(52, volume%/%52), volume%%52)), group][vol2 != 0]
#>    group vol2
#> 1:     A   52
#> 2:     A   52
#> 3:     A   52
#> 4:     A   44
#> 5:     B   45
#> 6:     C   52
#> 7:     C   52
```

Comment: I wasn't expecting a one-liner answer/solution.  Wow.

Comment: What does the extra empty square brackets `[ ]` do at the end of your solutions? I get the same result without them.

Comment: That's just to print it to the console. Just to show the result. You'll most likely take them off in your code.

Comment: Ah.  Okay.  It prints to my RStudio console both ways, whether I source with echo or not (what am I missing?).  I really like the idea of using `sign(volume%%52)` to add the remainder if it exists.  That trick seems particularly useful for all sorts of things.  I'm going to pick @r2evans' answer as the solution (this is similar to his 3rd solution, though more condensed) because of the variety of approaches, but this wins for brevity and deserves respect. Thank you!

Comment: You're right. It's not doing a by-reference assignment with the grouping operation. It should print either way.

Answer (score 2):

Vectorised and without grouping:

```
df1 <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "C"),
                  volume = c(200L, 45L, 104L))

n <- 52
idx <- df1$volume %/% n + ((sel <- df1$volume %% n) != 0)
out <- df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), idx),]
out$volume <- n
out$volume[cumsum(idx)[sel != 0]] <- sel[sel != 0]
##    group volume
##1       A     52
##1.1     A     52
##1.2     A     52
##1.3     A     44
##2       B     45
##3       C     52
##3.1     C     52
```

Comment: This is interesting.  It's a bit hard to follow until I break out each piece, but it certainly beats my code.  I think the assignment within an assignment is new to me: `sel <- df1$volume %%n`.  I can follow @stefan and @r2evans solutions (and probably apply them to new situations) easier, but this works and makes me think.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution using `aggregate` :

```
aggregate(.~group,df1,\(x) c(rep(52, x / 52), (x-1) %% 52 + 1))

  group         volume
1     A 52, 52, 52, 44
2     B             45
3     C     52, 52, 52
```

This results in a **list column** for volume (could be useful)

To transform it to a **long dataframe** we can either use `stack`:

```
with(
  aggregate(.~group,df1,\(x) c(rep(52, x / 52), (x-1) %% 52 + 1)),
  setNames(stack(setNames(volume,group))[2:1],names(df1))
  )

  group volume
1     A     52
2     A     52
3     A     52
4     A     44
5     B     45
6     C     52
7     C     52
8     C     52
```

Or alternatively use `unnest` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)

aggregate(.~group,df1,\(x) c(rep(52, x / 52), (x-1) %% 52 + 1)) %>% unnest(volume)

# A tibble: 8 × 2
  group volume
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 A         52
2 A         52
3 A         52
4 A         44
5 B         45
6 C         52
7 C         52
8 C         52
```